# Image of Linear transformacion between polynomials space

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm trying to solve this:

> Let $T$ be a linear transformation between the vector space of polynomials over the field of real numbers and $T$ defined $T(p(t))=p(t)-(\frac{dp(t)}{dt})$ find $ker(T)$ and $Im(T)$.

I found $ker(T)=0$, and I think the Image of T is the whole of polynomials space. I attempted to prove that for any polynomial given I can write it as another polynomial minus the 1st derivative of such polynomial, but my problem is the dregree of such polynomial.

I proved it to be true for polynomials of 3rd degree or less, and tried induction to make a generalization for polynomials of n degree but this got me nowhere.

Is there another way I can find $Im(T)$?

Comment: Is the space finite dimensional so the polynomials have a maximum degree?

Comment: @Dave No, that's the issue, it is an infinite dimensional space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sketch: (I'll abuse notation a little by denoting each polynomial by the expression in t that defines it)

$T(1) = 1$

$T(t) = t - 1$ so $T(t+1) = t$

$T(t^2) = t^2 - 2t$ so $T(t^2 + 2(t+1)) = t^2$ (using the previous line and linearity)

Generalise the pattern and observe that you now have all polynomials of the form  $p(t) = t^n$ in the image, which span $\mathbb R [t]$.